# Export an excel spreadsheet to PDF using xlwings.to_pdf in landscape mode?

Tags: xlwings

I am trying to export an excel worksheet to pdf using xlwings. It works fine but I need landscape, not portrait. I have landscape set in the print area in the spreadsheet but xlwings does not appear to see that. to_pdf does not appear to have a parameter for orientation.

Is it possible? If so how?

thanks in advance
Geoff

Comment: Yeah, I looked at that section before posting, but it seems to be aimed at generating reports embedded within existing PDFs. So I agree, I think it could be "support"

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had any problems with this myself.  However, you could try specifying the page orientation through Python.  If that doesn't work through `.to_pdf`, you could then try with the VBA `ExportAsFixedFormat` to see if that works.

```
sht1 = wb.sheets("Sheet1")

# Sheet orientation
sht1.api.PageSetup.Orientation = xw.constants.PageOrientation.xlLandscape

# Print using xlwings
sht1.to_pdf("Test1.pdf")
# Print using VBA ExportAsFixedFormat
sht1.used_range.api.ExportAsFixedFormat(Type=xw.constants.FixedFormatType.xlTypePDF,
                                        Filename="Test2.pdf")
```

Comment: Thanks, that gave me some ideas. I poked around in the python and found the following gave no errors:

import xlwings as xw
from xlwings.constants import PageOrientation
sheet.api.page_setup.orientation = xw.constants.PageOrientation.xlLandscape

However, the PDF was still in portrait.  I looked into the VBA method, but those symbols only show up in the window-specific files within xlwings, so being a Mac user it looks like I am still out of luck,